# How to make a torrent application for iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, utorrent

I was wondering if we could make an iphone app in which we can use torrent to download content.

Is it even possible can anyone give me the direction i should follow since m sort of new to iphone.

Thank alot in advance

Comment: What could you possibly download?

Comment: Songs , movies , apps, as there is a big percentage of jailbreak fon users so i wanted to make an app in which users can download and den by simple usb connect transfer data to Pc/mac. many aplication have been made for this to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider forking this project: https://github.com/kolyvan/kxtorrent

It uses the GNU Lesser General Public License (for better or worse) but it is still open source and you can fork it all like...

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be quite difficult:

1: the iphone can't realy download stuff and if it downloads stuff you can't use it in other apps like ipod or something. So you should think about what you want to download?

2: I don't think that this kind of app would make it to the app to the appstore, so you need to develop for jailbreaks.

But nevertheless good luck.

Comment: Yeah, targeting jailbreakers is odd, and Apple has started cracking down on it. Torrenting doesn't make sense anyway on mobile devices because they're so slow. Just torrent on your computer then copy over. This way you don't have to jail-break and you can use it with other applications (iTunes).

Comment: You're right. Maybe it's better to focus on remote controlling a torrent client on a PC than running it on a mobile with limited data plans.

Comment: @Mathias I think a more constructive answer to this question is needed. There are good reasons to allow mobile (iphone) clients to help in the distribution of data. Just because an iphone app uses bittorrent to distribute data does not automatically mean it will used for copyright infringement - talking about jailbreaking iphones in response to this question does not help us move forward. I would like to encourage you to edit this response.

Comment: The [App Store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) are pretty clear about this "22.4 Apps that enable illegal file sharing will be rejected". It doesn't matter if the primary purpose of the app is to download all those "Linux distros". If the App allows to download .torrent files it will be rejected. If the App uses bittorrent technology under the hood [it won't be rejected](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id665156116?mt=8#). But in this case nobody would call it a "torrent app".

Answer (score 0):

Well, torrentula is a popular iPhone bittorrent client, so you might want to start by taking a look at that.